# ServiceServer on Arduino -- Service requests will eventually hang

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have encountered an issue with rosserial wherein if I run a ServiceServer on my arduino -- after a variable number of requests to the service, the request will indefinitely hang. I have created a simplified example to re-create the problem (I added a Publisher as it seems to decrease the number of requests before failure):

**Arduino code:**

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <ArduinoHardware.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
#include <std_srvs/Empty.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;
using std_srvs::Empty;

// Create a publisher that generates a random die roll
std_msgs::UInt16 die;
ros::Publisher die_pub("random_die_roll", &die);

// Create a service server that takes nothing and returns nothing
void callback(const Empty::Request & req, Empty::Response & res)
{
  // Simulate function running for a non-deterministic amount of time
  delay(random(5,70));
}

ros::ServiceServer<Empty::Request, Empty::Response> server("get_nothing",&callback);

void setup()
{
  // Startup ROS
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertiseService(server);
  nh.advertise(die_pub);
}

void loop()
{
  // Publish die roll
  die.data = random(1, 7);
  die_pub.publish(&die);
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(75);
}
```

**Python node code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('test_arduino')
import rospy
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

def main():
    rospy.init_node("test_problem")
    rospy.wait_for_service('get_nothing')
    get_nothing_service = rospy.ServiceProxy('get_nothing', Empty)
    count = 0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        get_nothing_service()
        print "Got nothing...", count
        count += 1
        rospy.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 12.04
- ROS Groovy
- rosserial (4d34f24181b9570ac1f5a2be9ffbdbf4e8a3d59a)
- Seeeduino Mega w/ ATmega 1280

Any help is appreciated. I have a feeling it's just a mistake in my understanding.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77681/serviceserver-on-arduino----service-requests-will-eventually-hang/) by [River](https://answers.ros.org/users/549/river/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For someone in the future who may run into this problem, I got around it by creating a "psuedo-service". I used two publishers. The requester would publish a request and the server would publish a result after it heard the request. It worked very well, but it's not a "real" answer in my opinion.

---

Originally posted by [River](https://answers.ros.org/users/549/river/) with karma: 66 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under some circumstances, I believe this can be related to [pull request #308](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/308), where if the client exceeds one of the timeouts in `nh.spinOnce()`, the flag indicating it is configured will be set false, and the check before publishing will fail.  The rosserial_python node currently goes in to an infinite loop until it receives a response from the correct service server.

I worked around this by making the code that sets the configuration flag false upon timeout optional at compile time, but I don't think this is the most clean solution in general.

See my [fork](https://github.com/tom-f-oconnell/rosserial).  It may have changed, but commits around the time of this answer should have the change.

---

Originally posted by [TomOConnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/31846/tomoconnell/) with karma: 11 on 2017-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1